# Writing kubernetes extension

Tags: kubernetes

I need to add a REST API for Kubernetes rolling update feature. Is there a way we can write extensions for Kubernetes API? If that so is there any documentation about writing them?

Answer (score 2):

The [Extending the API](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/design/extending-api.md) doc describes how you can add resources to the Kubernetes API.

If you just want a REST API for rolling update, you should check out the [Deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/deployments.md) object.